# examples of RTSP to HTTP packetizing transcoding. Sirannon

Tags: ios, h.264, rtsp

I am trying find a way to transcode an rtsp stream to HTTP (iOS) so that I can view a rtsp stream on a ipad. The video is embedded in our SaaS web view, and launching a third party player is not a possibility.

I found [sirannon](http://sirannon.atlantis.ugent.be/) which according to the documentation can do this no prob.

However I am puzzled on how to actually execute.

Our rtsp stream is as such   rtsp:\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554\ch0_unicast_firststream

there is no .sdp file or anything. And vlc can play it fine.

But if i open a browser and attempt to open http://localhost:8080/RTSP-proxy/192.168.33.216/ch0_unicast_firststream

or
http://localhost:8080/RTSP-proxy/192.168.33.216:554/ch0_unicast_firststream

it gives me this error

> [1516250] Warning: core.HTTP-server: Handling RuntimeError: Could not
>   guess container type for
>   URL(/RTSP-proxy/192.168.33.216/ch0_unicast_firststream)
>   (core.HTTP-server.session-42)

So far I haven't found any goo dexamples using sirannon. I am also open to using VLC, but again, do not know if or how to do a rtsp to http conversion with VLC.

Comment: The reason why the "Could not guess container type for URL" happens is probably because of the parsing in src/Communicator/HTTP/HTTPSession.cpp where it tries to figure out the muxer. I haven't gotten the RTSP proxy to work yet either but if I do I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With wowza we are able preemptively start the root stream ahead of the http stream request.
With a delay of about 3 seconds, the client is able to connect nicely. Then we monitor the client list to see if it is empty, if so, we kill the stream.

Answer (score 0):

I've been digging into this for personal use and have gotten the same error. After some digging (notably in src/Communicator/HTTP/HTTPSession.cpp), I've made some progress.

While it's not explicitly in the documentation, it seems that you have to add the container type to the app type in the proxy, just as if you were streaming a file. As such:

```
http://localhost:8080/RTSP-proxy@[CONTAINER_TYPE]/192.168.33.216:554/ch0_unicast_firststream
```